# How to un-render elements on page when using react Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So i am looking to have a navbar that directs the user to different areas of my portfolio. What I want to happen is to have the navbar and img disappear once the user clicks on the li they want to go to. Basically want the user to land on a completely blank page that I can fill without the navbar and img. I'm sure this is an easy fix but here is my current router code:

```
import React from 'react'
import myPic from '../img/cropped.png'

import '../css/homePage.css'
import About from '../components/about.js'
import Projects from '../components/projects.js'
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route,
    Link
  } from "react-router-dom";


class HomePage extends React.Component{

    render(){
        return(
            <Router>
                <div className = "container">
                    <img src={myPic}></img>
                    <navbar>
                        <ul>
                            <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
                            <li><Link to="/projects">Projects</Link></li>
                            <li><Link to="/resume">Resume</Link></li>
                            <li><Link to="/contact">Contact</Link></li>
                        </ul>
                    </navbar>
                    <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/about' component={About}></Route>
                    <Route exact path = '/projects' component={Projects} > </Route>
                </Switch>

            
                
                </div>
            </Router>
        )
    }



}


export default HomePage
```

I know I haven't filled the entire Switch statement just wanted to get the other links working.

Comment: wrap you nav items in  a `Route` and set whatever `path` you want them to display on

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your navbar into a separate component, e.g. .

Wrap your `Navbar` Component with `withRouter()` before exporting.
Inside the render function of your `Navbar` component you can now render in condition to the `location`:

```
render() {
  const { location } = this.props;

  return (
    <ul>
      <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
      {location.pathname === '/' && <li><Link to="/projects">About</Link></li>}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

for more details see: [React Router: withRouter()](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter)